# Crash when using NSPredicate on NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I'm trying to use a predicate to sort an array of objects that have a date property of type NSDate.  However, when I try to use the predicate, an exception is raised and I get a strange error.

Here's the code:

```
NSDate * minDate = [NSDate date];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ ", minDate];
NSLog(@"%@",predicate);
NSArray * obs = [self.observations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Here's the error:

```
2012-02-04 13:14:32.380 MyApp[42845:17303] date >= CAST(315558000.000000, "NSDate")
2012-02-04 13:14:32.381 MyApp[42845:17303] -[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9392f80
2012-02-04 13:14:32.381 MyApp[42845:17303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9392f80'
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: What happens, if you set it to a date with day and month component?

Comment: I changed the date to just be the current date and get the same result.

Comment: Did you use the NSZombieEnabled tool?

Comment: Yes I did.  But this is not a bad access.  It's a unrecognized selector.

Comment: do the objects in observations really have the property date?

Comment: NSDate doesnt have length. this is a under-retain/overrelease of an object, that has. most likely NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the returned items were no longer of the type expected. After fixing the array, the code works as expected.